# Incrementally autofill a formula with a cell reference from another sheet? (=INDIRECT?)

Tags: excel, reference, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-indirect

I'm trying to autofill these formulas down, increasing the cell references to follow the pattern below.

The formulas average blocks of 12 and the cell references increase 11 at a time; I viewed some other related problems and I think the INDIRECT function is the way to go, but I'm having trouble working it into my formula:

Sheet2, Cell D2

```
 =IF(ISERROR(SUM('Sheet1'!D2:D13)),0,SUM('Sheet1'!D2:D13)/MAX(1,COUNTIF('Sheet1'!D2:D13,">0")))
```

Sheet2, Cell D3

```
=IF(ISERROR(SUM('Sheet1'!D14:D25)),0,SUM('Sheet1'!D14:D25)/MAX(1,COUNTIF('Sheet1'!D14:D25,">0")))
```

Sheet2, Cell D4

```
=IF(ISERROR(SUM('Sheet1'!D26:D37)),0,SUM('Sheet1'!D26:D37)/MAX(1,COUNTIF('Sheet1'!D26:D37,">0")))
```

Comment: yes, I"m sorry about that - let me fix that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UNTESTED. Please try:

```
=IF(ISERROR(SUM(INDIRECT("Sheet1!D"&ROW()+(ROW()-2)*11&":D"&ROW()+(ROW()-1)*11))),0,SUM(INDIRECT("Sheet1!D"&ROW()+(ROW()-2)*11&":D"&ROW()+(ROW()-1)*11))/MAX(1,COUNTIF(INDIRECT("Sheet1!D"&ROW()+(ROW()-2)*11&":D"&ROW()+(ROW()-1)*11),">0")))
```

Comment: I think the ISERROR formula is kicking in, it's returning "0"

Comment: The values are numeric (percentages) on Sheet1, but they are derived from links to another workbook. I should have mentioned that, I apologize.

Comment: 58.33%.  D12 and D13 are both zero.

Comment: I got it working.  I don't know if I was missing a parenthesis or something before or what, but I pasted it again and now it's working just fine.  Thank you for your patience.