# How do I increment a different sheet cell reference row as i autofill across columns?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

My goal is to autofill every column in a spreadsheet with a formula that automatically increments the referenced row as i copy it across columns. I've seen others reference using Indirect but I've ran into a few issues (I'm no excel expert, this spreadsheet is the deepest I've delved into formulas)

I'm trying to adapt the following formula such that the results is:

Cell B2:

```
=IF((MOD(($A2+(52-Sheet2!$E$2)),Sheet2!$D$2)=0),1,0)*Sheet2!$C$2
```

Cell C2:

```
=IF((MOD(($A2+(52-Sheet2!$E$3)),Sheet2!$D$3)=0),1,0)*Sheet2!$C$3
```

Cell D2:

```
=IF((MOD(($A2+(52-Sheet2!$E$4)),Sheet2!$D$4)=0),1,0)*Sheet2!$C$4
```

So far I've tried following this tutorial:
https://sourcedaddy.com/ms-excel/make-formulas-increment-rows.html

However I was unable to adapt it to handle pulling from a different sheet and splitting the cell reference, since I wanted the Columns to stay as is.

I also saw this user's question: [Incrementally autofill a formula with a cell reference from another sheet? (=INDIRECT?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25876857/incrementally-autofill-a-formula-with-a-cell-reference-from-another-sheet-ind)

But the answer is just "do this" so I'm struggling to make sense of the process involved. I don't mind being given the answer however I would appreciate a breakdown of the process so I can have a better understanding.

Many thanks.

Comment: What version of Excel do you have?

Comment: I'm using Microsoft Office Professional Plus 2019 (Microsoft Excel 2019 MSO (Version 2202))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### INDEX When Incrementing Rows By Columns

In cell `B2`:

```
=IF((MOD(($A2+(52-INDEX(Sheet2!$E:$E,COLUMN()))),INDEX(Sheet2!$D:$D,COLUMN()))=0),1,0)*INDEX(Sheet2!$C:$C,COLUMN())
```

- `INDEX($E:$E,2)` means `$E$2`; `INDEX($E:$E,3)` means `$E$3`;...
- In column `B`, `COLUMN()` means `2`; in column `C`, `COLUMN()` means `3`;
  ...
- In column `B`, `INDEX($E:$E,COLUMN())` means `$E$2`; in column `C`, `INDEX($E:$E,COLUMN())` means `$E$3`;...

Comment: Thanks, this worked perfectly. Could you explain a bit more about how this solution works?

Comment: Thanks, so the index takes the array for the desired column, and then you use column to get a numeric version in place of a letter? If I was wanting to apply this down rows as well, would any changes need to be made to the formula if only the A2 term needed to change?

Comment: I don't think so, that should be it. Best try, if something's wrong let us know. You described well what it does. `COLUMN()` is used as the row number for column `E` (the second argument of the `INDEX` function is `row`).

Comment: Perfect, Thankyou for clarifying that. Yes it did also work for rows. Thanks for your help and quick response :)